In Excel formula I am trying to split a total savings value between goals but once a goal is reached allocate to the remaining to the other goals
Edit for clarity:
In my table below you can see the results of my formula in D3:D6 however I would want D4 to show 15k as that is the target and the remaining to be allocated to D3 instead.
Also added a column to show the desired result.
In this table below I am trying to create a formula in Column D under 'Allocated' that allocates a split of D1 based on the goal and allocation %, once an allocated amount reaches the target amount it stops receiving any further allocation and the remaining would be spread to the other goals (distributed using ratios of the remaining allocation %)




A
B
C
D
E




1


Savings
£39,000



2
Goal Name
Target Amount
Allocation %
Allocated
Desired result


3
Goal 1
£2,000,000
10%
£7,571
£11,500


4
Goal 2
£15,000
25%
£18,929
£15,000


5
Goal 3
£5,000
40%
£5,000
£5,000


6
Goal 4
£7,500
25%
£7,500
£7,500



I had managed to make (brute force) a formula that almost worked that I will try to break down my logic below but there will hopefully be a better approach rather than trying to fix mine.
My formula taken from D3:
=IF(B3<=$D$1*C3,B3,($D$1-SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$6<=$C$3:$C$6*$D$1)*$B$3:$B$6))*(C3*(1/SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$6>$C$3:$C$6*$D$1)*$C$3:$C$6))))
IF B3<=D1*C3,B3 this should set the allocated amount to be no higher than the target, this issue is that in the above example for row 4, 39k * 0.25 = 9,750 meaning this IF returns a false.
$D$1-SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$6<=$C$3:$C$6*$D$1)*$B$3:$B$6)) calculates the sum of any row that would have returned a true above and deducts them from D1 to leave the remaining amount to allocate. In this case it sees row 5 & 6 as true so deducts 5k&7.5k from 39k to leave 26.5k
(C3*(1/SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$6>$C$3:$C$6*$D$1)*$C$3:$C$6)))) does similar as above to find the allocation % that would have been false for the if and sums them together. It divides 1 by this sum to give a factor the apply to the original allocation % for the new % in this case 1/( 0.1 + 0.25) = 2.86
2.86 * 0.1 = 0.286
+
2.86 * 0.25 = 0.714
total = 1 (100%)
The remaining amount to allocate is multiplied by the new % to get the final allocation.
This issue is this then doesn't account for if this new allocation takes the allocated amount above the target as seen in D4
I hope this makes sense and I really hope someone comes back with a really obvious way to do this that I am missing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Please add the new column with the desired result.

@rotabor done, hope it makes it more clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is the solution for you:

[D3]=LET(tgts,B3:B6,prcs,C3:C6,savs,D1,
  main,LAMBDA(alloc,percents,lmbd,
    LET(diff,tgts-alloc,remnd,IF(diff<0,0,diff),deal,(savs-SUM(alloc))*percents,
      cond,remnd<deal,remp,IF(cond,0,percents),na,IF(cond,remnd,deal)+alloc,
      IF(savs>SUM(na),lmbd(na,remp/SUM(remp),lmbd),na)
    )
  ),
  main(tgts*0,prcs,main)
)

The solution utilizes recursive calls to approach the current allocation to the resulting allocation which meets all conditions and consumes the whole savings.
If the allocation can't be reached the formula returns "#DIV/0!".
Step by step:

The final expression main(tgts*0,prcs,main) calls the main function with the initial allocation {0;0;0;0} and the initial percentage.
The main function (its definition starts at the second line) calculates in lines #3 to #5: a) the next allocation na in the defined limits; b) the next percentage remp/SUM(remp).
In line #5, if the next allocation doesn't consume the whole savings savs>SUM(na), the function calls itself recursively with the next allocation and percentage, otherwise it returns.


I'm not able to test this right now but it looks like it would do exactly what I need from your earlier comments and the image. It's ok if you don't want to but if you have time would you be able to explain what is happening here simply for my own learning? It looks really impressive.

This formula is in cell E3
=LET(max,D$1*C3:C6,
maxes,IF(max>B3:B6,B3:B6,0),
remain,D$1-SUM(maxes),
perc,SUM(IF(maxes=0,C3:C6)),
tot,IF(maxes=0,maxes+remain*C3:C6/perc),
maxes+tot)

Result of the calculation

This is a VBA code to calculate the (hopefully) correct result. This is placed in the sheet code module (reference reasons).
Sub frame is the caller, which transfer the first range to the recursive calculator.
Dim saving, rettable()

Function alloc(tabl())
Dim passtab()
j = 3
For i = 3 To UBound(tabl)
    If saving * tabl(i)(1)(1, 2) > tabl(i)(1)(1, 1) Then
        rettable(tabl(i)(0)) = tabl(i)(1)(1, 1)
        sumper = sumper + tabl(i)(1)(1, 2)
        saving = saving - tabl(i)(1)(1, 1)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve passtab(1 To j)
        passtab(j) = tabl(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
If i = 4 Then
    rettable(tabl(3)(0)) = saving
    Exit Function
End If
sumper = 1 - sumper
For i = 3 To j - 1
    passtab(i)(1)(1, 2) = passtab(i)(1)(1, 2) / sumper
Next i
alloc = alloc(passtab())
End Function

Sub frame()

saving = Range("D1")
lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim rettable(1 To lastrow)
ReDim dat(1 To lastrow)
For i = 3 To lastrow
    dat(i) = Array(i, Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).Value)
Next i
ret = alloc(dat())
For i = 3 To lastrow
    Cells(i, 5) = rettable(i)
Next i
End Sub







Savings
$39,000.00





Goal Name
Target Amount
Allocation %
Allocated



Goal 1
2,000,000
10%
£7,571
$11,500.00


Goal 2
15,000
25%
£18,929
$15,000.00


Goal 3
5,000
40%
£5,000
$5,000.00


Goal 4
7,500
25%
£7,500
$7,500.00




Sorry I probably wasn't clear enough but the issue with my formula and by the looks of it this one too is that D4 is returning 18k even though the target is 15k I would want it to be capped at 15k and the extra to be redistributed in this case to D3

Even though this didn't cover what I needed I have never used LET before and it seems so useful, I end up repeating calculations within larger formulas a lot and I never knew this existed

I see know what you need. But this requires a recursive calculation for always redividing the remainder of the savings on the allocation percentage. IMHO it will need VBA and not so easy as it seem.

Added a VBA code for possible correct result.
